# "ins" vs. "in das"

Tags: difference

In a phrasebook, I came across the phrase

> Wir gehen in das Wohnzimmer.

I was expecting this instead

> Wir gehen ins Wohnzimmer.

What's the relationship between these two forms?  (I.e. are they both common variants?  Are they both equally "correct"?  Are they completely synonymous?  Etc.)

Comment: Definitely for everyday use (e.g. when you invite your guests to move from the kitchen into the hall) *Wir gehen ins Wohnzimmer* would be the normal thing to say. *Wir gehen in das Wohnzimmer* sounds over-precise. If this appeares in a phrasebook, it is either because the author is not a native speaker, or because he wanted to spare the reader of the complexity of knowing that *ins* is short for *in das*.

Comment: Lt. Duden: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ins ins=in das.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In das** and **ins** are absolutely equivalent in your example.

(https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ins)

Prepositions can often merge with succeeding articles, mostly in the dative.

an + dem = **am**
an + das = **ans**
bei + dem = **beim**
in + dem = **im**
in + das = **ins**
von + dem = **vom**
zu + dem = **zum**
zu + der = **zur**

less formal:

auf + das = **aufs**
durch + das = **durchs**
für + das = **fürs**
hinter + dem = **hinterm**
hinter + das = **hinters**
hinter + den = **hintern**
über + dem = **überm**
über + das = **übers**
über + den = **übern**
um + das = **ums**
unter + dem = **unterm**
unter + das = **unters**
unter + den = **untern**
vor + dem = **vorm**
vor + das = **vors**

---

However, there are cases where they are not equal. Preposition and article cannot merge if the article is stressed (demonstrative pronouns) or the noun is specified more precisely afterwards (relative clause), e. g.

> Wir gehen <s>*ins*</s> **in das** Wohnzimmer(, das weiße Wände hat).
>   We go into that specific living room (with white walls).

---

There are a few special cases where the use of the short form (even the less formal ones) is mandatory:

- fixed expressions

  > *ans* Licht bringen
  >   *fürs* Erste
  >   *im* Sinne von
  >   *ums* Leben kommen
  >   *zum* ersten Mal
- substantiated infinitives

  > *beim* Essen
  >   Freude *am* Spielen
  >   *im* Sterben liegen
  >   *vom* Segeln träumen
- geographical proper names with articles

  > *am* Rhein
  >   Frankfurt *am* Main
  >   *vom* Schwarzwald bis *zum* Bodensee
  >   Beziehungen *zur* Türkei
- time specifications

  > *am* 5. Juni
  >   *am* Montag
  >   *im* Juni
  >   *am* gleichen Tag

Comment: The middle part seems not to be true for entire Germany. I (southern Germany) would not have any problem with the following sentences: "*In welches von beiden Zimmern gehen wir? Wir gehen **ins** Zimmer, das blaue Tapeten hat.*" However for the answer: "*Wir gehen **in das** Zimmer und nicht **ins** andere.*" you would be right.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I agree, hardly any German would have a problem with that, especially not in spoken language. Nonetheless, it wouldn't be quite perfect German.

Answer (score 4):

One is simply a shortened version of the other. There is no difference in meaning or applicability, except you need the demonstrative *das* separately to be able to stress it.

*Ins* is much more common in oral communication (simply because it is shorter), while *in das* might show up in written form more often.

It is a bit similar to the difference between "it is" and "it's" in English.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that the contraction of *in das* to *ins* was optional.  Thanks for clarifying that.  (Also, in case anyone thinks this observation is obvious, in Spanish, the contractions *del* (from *de el*) and *al* (from *a el*) are not optional; to use *de el <NOUN>* or *a el <NOUN>* would be substandard Spanish.)

Comment: If you have to choose, rather choose the contracted forms *ins*, *zum*, etc. The uncontracted forms are generally used to stress *das* or *dem*, in my experience. Even in writing, the contracted forms are more common.

Comment: There is an important difference! The demonstrative *das* can not be shortened. I.e.: „in DAS Zimmer geh ich nicht“ is different from „Ins ZIMMER  geh ich nicht“. This is a prime reason for often using the contracted form even in formal writing!

Answer (score 4):

They are virtually identical. *ins* is short for *in das* (in the same way as *im/in dem, zum/zu dem...*).

In certain contexts the sentence with *in das* could put slightly more stress on the fact that you are going to this particular room and not another room.

I'd use the second form more often.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them mean the same. "in das" is just shortened to "ins". I am just warming up with my German and find that I tend to use "in das" in place of "ins". However, I usually hear Germans use "ins" more frequently.